# How do I create a "link" between two mySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, field

I have two tables that look as Follows:

Person (Table Name)

Name1/Phone1/Email1/Address1/Organization1/Notes1 (Fields)

Organization (Table Name)

Organization1/Phone2/Email2/Address2/Web2/Notes2 (Fields)

Organization1 is the only field in common between the two tables.

When I display data on a person, I want to also check and see if there is data on their organization and display it as well if it exists.  I'm using PHP to interface with mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This post is an explanation of relations, not code for you to use. If you want that, look elsewhere**
Well, connections between tables are called relations.  There are 3 types of relations.

1) One -> One  -  This type of relation means 1 row is related to 1 other row in a different table

2) One -> Many -  This type of relation means 1 row is related to a variable number of rows in a different table.
An example may be A folder can have multiple files, but a file can't have multiple folders.  So in this case the 1 would be the folder, and the many would be the files.

3) Many -> Many -  This type of relation means many rows can relate to many other rows.
An example may be labels.  You can label many things the same name (desk appliance for example), and each thing can have multiple labels (a lamp can have both desk appliance & light labels).

.
So now that you know the different relations, we will go into your question.  The relation you are looking at is a one to many, one corporation can have many people, but a person can only have one corporation.  I suppose a person could work for multiple people, but that is much more complex (so we'll skip it).

One to many relations are by far the most common, and are pretty easy to do.  This is where joins come in (left, right, and inner joins).  Tizag has an excellent tutorial on joins here: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks it helps. This might be another post but what about storing bookmarks for a peson. One person can have many different bookmarks, and one bookmark can have many different people, so this would be considered many -> many. Correct?

Comment: Well, depends on how you design it.  If you don't mind having duplicate bookmarks (if, say each also writes a personal description for the bookmark, but with the same url).  Then it would be one -> many (can't share user bookmarks with other users, because each one has different descriptions, etc).  If you are designing it so that there are no duplicates then yes, it would be a many -> many.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), but you need to [use the InnoDB storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899250/139010) (MyISAM does not support foreign keys yet).

Comment: A little off topic, but will there ever be FK support for MyISAM?

Comment: @RexM no idea, don't really care.

Comment: @RexMorgan seems like a definitive "no," 12+ years later: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12971246/139010

Comment: Thanks. I don’t even remember asking the question!

Answer (score 3):

You need to `JOIN` the tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Person LEFT JOIN Organization ON Person.Organization = Organization.Name;
```

This assumes the relationship is the Organization Name. I've done a `LEFT JOIN` since you said *if exists*. Check out [this tutorial](http://phpweby.com/tutorials/mysql/32) for more detail on joining tables.

**Note:** I agree and would recommend making your database more relational by adding Primary Keys and using them as Foreign Keys in your other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Make your tables look something like this:

Person_ID, Name, Phone, Email, Address, Organisation_ID, Notes (or if you have multiple notes, create a seperate table that maps person_id to a note).

Organisation_ID, Name, Phone, Email, Address, Web, Notes.

Select your person, then if Organisation_ID exists, select the Organisation where Organisation_ID equals the ID you obtained from the person row.

Comment: Yes. Make it the table index, and keep it unique. Depending on how your application is structured it might mean changing some things, but this is the 'easiest' method of linking the tables. The SQL method Jason uses will be faster, but I'm not really comfortable with SQL so tend to use the PHP method :P