# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm having some issues with a foreign key constraint, and am probably not putting the code together properly.

The idea is that the airports table will only accept a type value that is in the apType table.  If the type is not in the apType table, it should generate an error.  However, I have been testing this and I am unable to get it to generate an error, it just places the type entered into the database and is happy with it.

Airport Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `airport`(
`id` int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`rwyCount` int,
`lat` float(6),
`lon` float(6),
`type` varchar(255), 
constraint FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES apType(type) match simple
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

apType Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `apType`(
`id` int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` varchar(255) NOT NULL
 )ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

insert of values for apType (these are the only values that should be valid):

```
INSERT INTO `apType` (`type`) VALUES ('private'),('public'),('military');
```

Insert that should generate an error:

```
 insert into `airport` (`name` , `rwyCount` , `type` , `lat` , `lon`) values ('failland', 3 , 'space', 45.588611, -122.5975);
```

Can anyone figure out this issue?

Comment: There are articles all over the web that explain this.  Have you tried using your favourite search engine?  It's a very productive skill to learn - the ability to research your own answers to your own problems.

Comment: I did indeed, and many of the answers provided useful information, but nothing that was able to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that foreign keys have not yet been implemented in the DB engine that you are using.
[Why doesn't MySQL's MyISAM engine support Foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971246/why-doesnt-mysqls-myisam-engine-support-foreign-keys)

Maybe consider switching to InnoDb?

Comment: I tried that and i get a #1005 - Can't create table 'todtm-db.airport' (errno: 150)  error.

Comment: What you have to do, before you create the second table, is create an index. Create index ix on apType(type); . This is because you are not referencing the primary key :) Then, create table airport.

Comment: I completely forgot I had it referencing something other than the primary key.  Fixed it, it works, and give the proper error.  Thank you