# Fail to create relationship between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, relation

I have two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `login` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `Books` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `available` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `availabledate` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am trying to create a relationship between those two, so that one user may have multiple books (user_id) but whatever I'm doing I'm getting errors. Either

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bookstore`.,
>   CONSTRAINT `books_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`
>   (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

or before I didn't use unsigned int in the Books table and I said that default value is 0 (which I would prefere but I don't think I can do that?) In that case I got error 150.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend, to change your database schema. Why?

1. Can a book exist without having a user? If yes, you shouldn't have a foreign key from books referencing users. Can a user exist without having a book? If yes, you shouldn't have a foreign key from users referencing books.
2. Can a user have multiple books? And a book multiple users? If yes, you have a m:n relationship. This means you need a bridge table.

In your tables you don't need foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `login` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Books` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `available` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `availabledate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And a bridge table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE books_users (
book_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
user_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (book_id, user_id),
KEY idx_user_id (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY fk_books (book_id) REFERENCES Books(id),
FOREIGN KEY fk_users (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This solves both problems and is common practice.

To query both users and books in one query, you join them like this:

```
SELECT
whatever
FROM
Books b
INNER JOIN books_users bu ON b.id = bu.book_id
INNER JOIN users u ON bu.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE user_id = 1 /*for example*/
;
```

If you want to insert something in the tables, just do the insert and get the id which was generated for the row with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`, then insert this id in the `books_users` bridge table.

Updates don't affect anything, you can simply perform them on `users` or `books`. If you really really have to update the auto_increment column (which usually isn't needed and not recommended) you can add `ON UPDATE CASCADE` after the foreign keys in the `books_users` table.

Comment: @Fengson Please consider my answer, although Chintan Gor has more upvotes. He solves the problem, that you can't add a foreign key to the table, but your table design might still be wrong.

Comment: I created a tables as you said, because of the fact that I want to have both books and users alone, too. But can you tell me how can I save and gather informations this way? When I place an order, what do I  update? And when I want to display asd well?

Comment: @Fengson Edited my answer. Does it answer your questions?

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines and try again

> change `user_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` to `user_id
>   int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

and

> `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, to  `id` int(11) NOT
>   NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

and

> `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, to `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

Finally try

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `login` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `Books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `available` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `availabledate` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Mysql then you must use InnoDB database engine to enable relationship between two tables 
MyISAM  will not allow this relationship

```
alter table `users` add constraint `FK_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

or you can use this query for cascade edit delete

```
alter table `users` add constraint `FK_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

This is your new DDL for two tables try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `available` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `availabledate` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `login` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: let me check sir your defination

Comment: please check I added new query to add relation for edit and delete

Comment: Surely MyISAM's not bothered?

Comment: @Strawberry yes sir please see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971246/why-doesnt-mysqls-myisam-engine-support-foreign-keys

Comment: Precisely. MyISAM simply ignores the constraint. The relationship is not disallowed!

Comment: @Strawberry you mean I can use Relation query in MyIsam and it will not giving any error?
although relation will not consider by Mysql..

Comment: Exactly. It's just ignored. :-)

Comment: ThankYou sir I did not tried this query in MYIsam engine because from first people thought me that it is not allowed in this engine so I never tried this ....Thanks Again :D