# Generate Database MyISAM Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, innodb, myisam

I am using Doctrine to generate and update my DB based on my Entities. Furthermore, I am using a MyISAM engine on my tables. To do so I have added my annotations like:

```
/** (...) @ORM\Table(name="user",options={"engine":"MyISAM", "charset"="utf8"}) */
```

The tables were generated as MyISAM normally, but when I try to update them now doctrine is trying to generate the FKs. Then I got:

```
 General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I know MyISAM does not support FKs, is there a way to tell doctrine to skip the creation of FKs?

> I am using both **orm:schema-tools:update** (in DEV) and **migrations** (in PROD). Also I am using zf2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/rwWXZ7faPsA) I came with a solution.

I added an event listener to the EM.

```
$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new DropForeignKeysListener());
```

This event drop all FKs from the schema generated from the annotations, as:

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Event\GenerateSchemaEventArgs;

class DropForeignKeysListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args) {
        $schema = $args->getSchema();

        $table_names = $schema->getTableNames();
        foreach ($table_names as $table_name) {
            $table = $schema->getTable($table_name);
            $fks = $table->getForeignKeys();

            foreach ($fks as $fk => $obj) {
                $table->removeForeignKey($fk);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(ToolEvents::postGenerateSchema);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The MyISAM storage engine doesn't support row-level locking, foreign keys and it doesn't even support transactions. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971246/why-doesnt-mysqls-myisam-engine-support-foreign-keys) for a more detailed answer.

If you don't have any specific & valid reason to use MyISAM, i strongly recommend to use InnoDB instead.

You may also want to read this [comparison between InnoDB and MyISAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines).

Comment: I know that it does not support FKs (I maybe don't let it clear in the question), I just want to avoid the creation when I try to update the DB. Otherwise I have to dump the SQL and remove the creation statements manually.

Also I can chage it, but now even if I do so I will keep curious about how shall I proced to avoid it. For sample, now I am thinking in use an event subscriber like here: [Telling Schema-Tool to ignore an entity](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/rwWXZ7faPsA). That is more close to the answer I am looking for.