# [HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

**application_user**

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table application_user
(
  id        bigint auto_increment
    primary key,
  email     varchar(255) not null,
  is_active bit          null,
  name      varchar(255) not null,
  password  varchar(255) not null,
  surname   varchar(255) not null,
  username  varchar(255) not null
)
  engine = MyISAM;
```

I have a table that generated by hibernate.
I want to create a table and add a foreign key manually.

So far I tried this

**application_user_log**

```
CREATE TABLE application_user_log (
  log_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fk_user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  old_user_name BIGINT NOT NULL,
  new_user_name BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (log_id),
  FOREIGN KEY  (fk_user_id) REFERENCES application_user(id)
) ;
```

And I got this error message.: `[HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Why I got this error?

Comment: Because MyISAM does not support foreign keys

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971246/why-doesnt-mysqls-myisam-engine-support-foreign-keys)).

Comment: So what should I do to create a table that has a foreign key that referenced to a table which created by hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why my answer got converted into a comment, but I knonw that MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys. [You can read details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971246/why-doesnt-mysqls-myisam-engine-support-foreign-keys) here.