# Foreign key incorrectly formed error in MySQL in Manjaro Linux

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux, manjaro

[image]

"user table" is created successfully. Every columns and types is the same as "users table." But when I create an association table named "user_role," "user table" cannot be called. I only get this error in using MySQL with MariaDB. Installing mysql in windows and using like that is fine. Without changing that table name, is there anything I can do to make it right?

Two tables are dumped because I forget where did I put my original code. But I'll be the same.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`course_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FKj8ce5cjkm11igsffixdxexrr9` (`course_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`course_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `course_id` (`course_id`),
CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `role` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`role_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create table `user_role`(
`id` int auto_increment not null,
`user_id_fk` bigint,
`role_id_fk` int,
primary key (`id`),
foreign key (`user_id_fk`) references `user`(`id`),
foreign key (`role_id_fk`) references `role`(`id`)
);
```

--> `references user(id)` is not working but `references users(id)` is working. Is there any way to make it work? Or just change the name?

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of image, best with http://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: I hope you are just joking now. Asking for code([Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to reproduce your scenario in order to help is wasting of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you don't have one table name being the plural of another (`user` vs `users`); it can lead to typos.

Don't use MyISAM for anything.  (with rare exceptions)

If that is a many-to-many mapping table follow the tips in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Thanks, someone has already answered it for me. But I'll upvote for you. One question. I didn't tell MariaDB to use MyISAM or AnnoDB. I just created a table. How did it automatically choose MyISAM?

Comment: Old versions of MariaDB defaulted (for new tables) to MyISAM.

Comment: I think the default changed with 5.5; what version are you using?  Or perhaps you carried forward an old my.cnf when upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key is across tables defined with different engines(InnoDB and MyISAM):

```
create table `user_role`(
`id` int auto_increment not null,
`user_id_fk` bigint(20),   -- matching data types
`role_id_fk` int(11)       -- matching data types
,primary key (`id`) 
,foreign key (`role_id_fk`) references `role`(`id`)
,foreign key (`user_id_fk`) references `user`(`id`)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=acc30d4da28edb63d77d6a825ff69ee3)**

Related: [Why doesn't MySQL's MyISAM engine support Foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971246/why-doesnt-mysqls-myisam-engine-support-foreign-keys)

Comment: Thanks. Now, I know why it's important to upload the code.

Comment: @DraculaOppa  [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I didn't set the engine when I write a query. How does it happen?

Comment: @DraculaOppa - There is a `default_storage_engine` which is optionally set in my.cnf.  Suggest that you set that to `innodb` and get in the habit of saying `ENGINE=InnoDB` on the end of `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: Yeah, I always make table without telling the ENGINE. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to put it so as not to mess up like that again.